# Ajax Post always returns an error

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, json

Hi i am trying to call a C# method to return a json but keep getting errors.

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: 'ReportList.aspx/GetReports',
   dataType: 'json',
   success: function (response) {
       dataset = response.d;
   },
   error: function (response, success, error) {
        alert("Error: " + error);
   }
});
```

The error i am getting reads as:

> Unexpected token <

Previously i had **contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',** added but that returned a internal server error.

I would like to call json so that i may populate a javascript.datatable.

C# Function:

```
public string GetReports()
{
   System.Data.DataSet d;
   d = (System.Data.DataSet)Session["dsHistory"];

   System.Data.DataSet DsNew = new System.Data.DataSet("cdreports");

   System.Data.DataTable table1 = new System.Data.DataTable("reports");
   table1.Columns.Add("id");
   table1.Columns.Add("name");
   table1.Columns.Add("regAndId");
   table1.Columns.Add("type");
   table1.Columns.Add("timeStamp");
   foreach (System.Data.DataRow row in d.Tables["company"].Rows)
   {
      table1.Rows.Add(row["rc_id"], row["companyname"], row["companyregnumber"], "Company", row["rc_timestamp"]);
   }
   foreach (System.Data.DataRow row in d.Tables["director"].Rows)
   {
      table1.Rows.Add(row["rd_id"], row["firstname"] + " " + row["surname"], row["idnumber"], "Director", row["rd_timestamp"]);
   }
   DsNew.Tables.Add(table1);

   string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(DsNew, new DataSetConverter());

    return json;
}
```

Comment: Check the network tab of your browser's dev tools to see what the response looks like.

Comment: @JasonP response is always null, It never reaches my C# function, just throws the error mentioned above.

Comment: `GetReports()` should be `static` and have the `[WebMethod]` attribute.

Comment: @JasonP I have made GetReports a [WebMethod] and static, i still have the same error.

Comment: What does the request look like? What's the response code?

Comment: @JasonP this is what i see in my javascript errors: POST http://localhost:64220/logged/reportlist.aspx/GetReports 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: The path to my page is correct, and then GetReports is my method name.

Comment: Are you logging the exception with the stack trace? Something is going wrong on your page, you'll need to debug it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure trace is disabled on the page. Sometimes ajax calls don't work if page tracing is enabled.